# JFrog XRay extension not scanning Libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, artifactory, jfrog-xray

I have added the JFrog extension in Visual Studio Code and connected it with an Artifactory instance. When I start scanning it starts scanning then shows 404 error.

Screenshot attached [image]

[image: Bottom Right]

Answer (score 1):

one can try this

https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-vscode-extension/issues/99

I got it connected after connecting/disconnect.